# Easy homework questions about seasons and daytime

Tags: homework, sun, seasons, equator

The following homework assignment is supposed to be easy, but there seems to be information missing from the questions asked <sub>(or at the very least knowledge from OP)</sub>.

- At which width circle does the sun shine perpendicularly?
- How long is a **day** south of the south polar circle?
- Which **season** is starting in the southern hemisphere?

The following picture was included.

[image]

Comment: English translations for the labels in the graphic would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry @BillDOe, I can't find a picture with English translations.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I posted an answer, but you should explain why were you struggling to answer that question.

Comment: @CamiloRada What if you turned the sun, would the answer to question one remains the same?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers What do you mean by "turned the sun"?

Comment: @CamiloRada - Joint effort of my daughter and me and English is not our native language :). She meant what if the Sun in the image is on the left side instead of the right side of the image.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers when the Earth has gone around the sun so that the sun "comes from the left" in the image... then it will be Northern Hemisphere Winter Solstice (Southern Hemisphere Summer Solstice) [about December 21st].  The Earth will rotate on its own axis each day, but the sun will be coming from the right still.  It's only when the Earth has traveled 180 degree around the sun that it would come from the opposite side.

Comment: I cleaned up your English a little -- please feel free to revert the edit if you feel I made any incorrect changes. By the way, the label "zon in het [zenit](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenit_(astronomie))" is a strong hint about the answer to the first question :-).

Comment: @Pont - only if *zenit* means anything to you ;). Thank you for cleaning up.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers In that case, as JeopardyTempest say it would be northernn hemisphere summer winter. And the answers would be 1) Tropic of Capricorn (10 1/2 uur labeled circle) 2) 24h of sunlight 3) Summer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure depicts the Northern hemisphere summer solstice, given that, there is no information missing:

- **At which width circle does the sun shines perpendicularly?**

The one labeled "13 1/2 uur" that corresponds to the Tropic of Cancer

- **How long is a day south of the southpole circle?**

If we understand "day" as the length of daytime, the answer is zero: The sun never rises that day south of the southern polar circle.

- **Which season starts at the southern hemisphere?**

Winter

Comment: what tripped me up was that I didn't view the questions in light of that specific constellation *(time of year?)* of the earth.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Be aware that I corrected it. I was switching the names of the tropics.